# notepad++ regex search and replace in code

Tags: notepad++

I want to convert

```
$this->cols['project_nr']['value']
```

into

```
$this->project_nr
```

using notepad++, using regex search and replace.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

Find what: `cols\['(.*?)'(.*\])`
Replace with: `$1`